# Angular Material Expansion Panels in IOS 8

Tags: ios, angular, angular-material, accordion

I'm running to a bug with Angular Material expansion panels in IOS 8.1 (the bug does not appear on IOS 10+, have yet to test 9). If I use code from the [example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lpqkamaqobq?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts), the expansion panels appear and open on click, but do not close on a second click.

Each click produces the following error in the safari web inspector console:

```
ERROR – Error {line: 5169, column: 46, sourceURL: "http://localhost:4200/vendor.js"}
defaultErrorLogger — vendor.js:56067
handleError — vendor.js:56113
(anonymous function) — vendor.js:58982:99
invoke — polyfills.js:7499
run — polyfills.js:7249
runOutsideAngular — vendor.js:58177
tick — vendor.js:58982
(anonymous function) — vendor.js:58867:110
invoke — polyfills.js:7499
onInvoke — vendor.js:58218
invoke — polyfills.js:7498
run — polyfills.js:7249
run — vendor.js:58132
next — vendor.js:58867:85
(anonymous function) — vendor.js:57949
__tryOrUnsub — vendor.js:135347
next — vendor.js:135285
_next — vendor.js:135220
next — vendor.js:135195
next — vendor.js:134960
emit — vendor.js:57933
checkStable — vendor.js:58187
onLeave — vendor.js:58254
onInvokeTask — vendor.js:58212
invokeTask — polyfills.js:7531
runTask — polyfills.js:7299
invokeTask — polyfills.js:7607
invokeTask — polyfills.js:8651
globalZoneAwareCallback — polyfills.js:8677
defaultErrorLogger — vendor.js:56067
```

I'm curious if other people experience this same issue or if someone knows of a solution to it.

I'm using Angular 6, material 6.4.0, and IOS 8.1 (running on iPad Air simulator). My included polyfills are:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

import 'web-animations-js';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Comment: Any errors in your XCode console?

Comment: Oh good point. None in the xcode console but I did notice one in the safari web inspector. Will update the question

Comment: Did you try on a actual device rather than an emulator?

Comment: No, I don't have access to one